# How to make a chrome texture in eevee?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

I'm somewhat new to blender, and brand new to eevee so if I say anything wrong I apologize.

How would I go about making a chrome material in eevee? I've tried to reduce the roughness and play around with every setting but I can't get anything to look good.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making good looking materials is dependent on a number of things like

Shape: Chrome is usually applied to an organic looking metal object like a fender.

Environment: A nice environment that make reflections in the surface. Make sure to use a reflection probe in EEVEE.

Material

Color: Chrome R=0.550,G=0.556,B=0.554 (https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/Materials/PhysicallyBased)

Metallic: A metal material is always 1.0 in metallic.

Roughness: It's usually a matter of taste but since it is Chrome it should be fairly shiny. Is really good to have a noise texture here so you will get variation and imperfections.

[image: chrome cube]

[image: Material]

Comment: Thanks! So what does the Principled BSDF node look like?

Comment: I updated my answer with a screenshot of the material setup.