# Chrome texture in eevee blender 2.82

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

For some reason, i cannot seem to get a chrome texture in blender eevee? Does anyone have a blend file i can look at?

I've looked at this:

[How to make a chrome texture in eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129785/how-to-make-a-chrome-texture-in-eevee/129788)

but even using the same node setup, the render I get isn't as good, so it's a question of the entire scene, or something i'm missing in how the scene is lit. So i'd like to have an entire blend file instead, for 2.82.

Comment: You can actually try some keyword and most likely someone already asked about it. Hope this link helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129785/how-to-make-a-chrome-texture-in-eevee/129788 Good luck with the project :)

Comment: It would be nice to have a blend file that has realistic lighting

Comment: You can use HDRI file for more realistic lighting, there are bunch of tutorials to use that if you are not familiar. You can get some for free at sites like https://hdrihaven.com/

Comment: Thanks! that's really helpful. It does make some difference, but at the same time i'm wondering if it's how the scene is setup that helps in the chrome material renders. For example this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5pb6pjdgOE , I cannot quite replicate the default setup in the beginning itself. The white principled bsdf shader doesn't have the same appearance in my scenes

Comment: did you setup the same lighting tho? the default white principled bsdf is gonna be always 0.5 specular and 0.5 roughness in white (slightly grey). it must be the same appearance, unless what you mean by 'appearance' is lighting, etc.

Comment: I'll write another question based on the second video. But what i meant was, even having the same default setting material as in the video, the render preview isn't the same. The hdri environment helps in giving some pseudo light reflection, but it isn't the same