# How do I add (a chrome) texture without a 2D image? "TxDiffuse missing" error

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I'm importing multiple identical linked objects into a game asset.  I want the objects chrome.  I found this thread on "making a chrome texture in eevee:" [How to make a chrome texture in eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129785/how-to-make-a-chrome-texture-in-eevee)

Following the thread, I created a new material called "chrome" and used the settings as indicated.  I used the shader tab to create the node layout as pictured in the thread.  The objects appear chrome-like.

I did not UV unwrap the (parent) object as I'm happy with the chrome appearance on the objects.  I wouldn't know where/how to unwrap the object UV islands as I don't have an 2D image, just the chrome appearance generated by "chrome" settings as indicated.

When I import this modified asset into the game dev editor it shows the new material "chrome", but it gives an error message "TxDiffuse is null", i.e. that the material has no assigned texture.
I'm very new to this and clearly don't yet understand materials versus shaders versus textures.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're exporting your material outside of Blender, the node setup you used to create the material will no longer work. It's like the node setup is a dynamic material and to export it you need to save a still version of it (i.e. bake it).

There's a really good explanation of how to do that here: [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

In essence, you choose a look you like and create a texture (a still image) for the object's surface. When you export that object into whatever other program you're using, you apply that texture (image) as its material, and you get the same look you had when you baked the material. The UV map is what is used to assign the right parts of the texture you made to the right parts of the object. Of course, that means the material isn't dynamic anymore, so you can either deal with that or combine the texture with whatever builtin material editor the program you're using has.

For a metallic material that has a lot of reflection going on, a baked texture probably isn't the best choice, so its better to use built-in tools in whatver program you're exporting to.

Comment: Thanks, that starts to turn on a light for me.  The explanation says:

"Add a texture node to the objects material(s) and select the new image. If there are more than 1 material repeat this for each one of them (easier to copy that Image Texture node and paste it into all materials)."  

Are you able to articulate and explain that process - of "adding a texture node to the object's material" - more clearly?  And if I "add a texture node to the object's material", won't that change the appearance of the material?

Comment: By "add a texture node" it just means you should create an image texture node with the new texture and leave it in the material nodespace without connecting it to anything. Since it's not connected to anything it won't change the material's appearance.Blender will use that texture node as directions for where to save the baked material texture.